# I cannot build my project on Vercel, but it works perfectly in dev

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

my code:
import Photo1 from "../utility/images/ourimages/9.jpeg";

error: Module not found: Can't resolve '../utility/images/ourimages/9.jpeg' in '/vercel/path0/pages'.
I tried changing the paths to ./../utility/images/ourimages/9.jpeg" and similar variations but it failed every time.(thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

The Next.js docs explain [Static File Serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving).

The typical way to do this in Next.js would be to put your image(s) in the `public` folder in the root directory, then you can reference them in your code starting from the base directory. You shouldn't need to import an image. For example, if you put `9.jpeg`, you should be able to reference it like this:

```
<Image src="/9.jpg"...
```